# json to csv using jq on large json file

Tags: csv, jq

I have a very large JSON that contains sports data output from a sports simulation website.  I am working on a script that outputs player gamelog data into a csv file.

The JSON is too large to post but there are over 700 games in the games[] array. 2 teams[] in each team array and 10 players in each player[] array.

My current code is:

```sh
jq -r '.games[] | [.teams[] | .tid, .ovr, .won, .lost, (.players[] | .pid, .gs, .min, .fg, .fga)] | join(", ")' > file.csv
```

This code puts all of the player data (both teams) for each game on one line of the csv. I would like one line per player in the csv.

I have used **`map`** and **`join("\n")`** in previous scripts but the nested arrays are giving me problems.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. I.p., please show a short but telling JSON input and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: Please show your JSON, otherwise it is impossible to give useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why the Stackoverflow community is often claimed to be "unwelcoming to new users". Here is the community completing your question with an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (reversed from your given `jq` expression):

```json
{
    "games": [
        {
            "teams": [
                {
                    "tid": 111,
                    "ovr": 112,
                    "won": 114,
                    "lost": 118,
                    "players": [
                        {
                            "pid": 11111,
                            "gs": 11112,
                            "min": 11114,
                            "fg": 11118,
                            "fga": 111116
                        },
                        {
                            "pid": 11121,
                            "gs": 11122,
                            "min": 11124,
                            "fg": 11128,
                            "fga": 111216
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tid": 121,
                    "ovr": 122,
                    "won": 124,
                    "lost": 128,
                    "players": [
                        {
                            "pid": 12111,
                            "gs": 12112,
                            "min": 12114,
                            "fg": 12118,
                            "fga": 121116
                        },
                        {
                            "pid": 12121,
                            "gs": 12122,
                            "min": 12124,
                            "fg": 12128,
                            "fga": 121216
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "teams": [
                {
                    "tid": 211,
                    "ovr": 212,
                    "won": 214,
                    "lost": 218,
                    "players": [
                        {
                            "pid": 21111,
                            "gs": 21112,
                            "min": 21114,
                            "fg": 21118,
                            "fga": 211116
                        },
                        {
                            "pid": 21121,
                            "gs": 21122,
                            "min": 21124,
                            "fg": 21128,
                            "fga": 211216
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "tid": 221,
                    "ovr": 222,
                    "won": 224,
                    "lost": 228,
                    "players": [
                        {
                            "pid": 22111,
                            "gs": 22112,
                            "min": 22114,
                            "fg": 22118,
                            "fga": 221116
                        },
                        {
                            "pid": 22121,
                            "gs": 22122,
                            "min": 22124,
                            "fg": 22128,
                            "fga": 221216
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To generate one line of output per player, containing tid, ovr, won, lost, pid, gs, min, fg, and fga:

```
.games[].teams[]
  | . as $team
  | .players[]
  | [$team["tid", "ovr", "won", "lost"], .pid, .gs, .min, .fg, .fga]
  | join(", ")
```

The array construction can be simplified if you want all properties of a player in the output:

```
.games[].teams[]
  | . as $team
  | .players[]
  | [$team["tid", "ovr", "won", "lost"], .[]]
  | join(", ")
```

Output:

```
111, 112, 114, 118, 11111, 11112, 11114, 11118, 111116
111, 112, 114, 118, 11121, 11122, 11124, 11128, 111216
121, 122, 124, 128, 12111, 12112, 12114, 12118, 121116
121, 122, 124, 128, 12121, 12122, 12124, 12128, 121216
211, 212, 214, 218, 21111, 21112, 21114, 21118, 211116
211, 212, 214, 218, 21121, 21122, 21124, 21128, 211216
221, 222, 224, 228, 22111, 22112, 22114, 22118, 221116
221, 222, 224, 228, 22121, 22122, 22124, 22128, 221216
```

Although the next question is why use `join(",")` when jq already as has perfectly-fine `@csv` filter (automatically handling escaping etc.)?

```
.games[].teams[]
  | . as $team
  | .players[]
  | [$team["tid", "ovr", "won", "lost"], .[]]
  | @csv
```

(`join(",")` will generate malformed CSV for string values containing a double quote).

The variable-assignment to `$team` can be changed to a destructuring assignment:

```
.games[].teams[]
  | . as { $tid, $ovr, $won, $lost }
  | .players[]
  | [$tid, $ovr, $won, $lost, .[]]
  | @csv
```

---

A solution without variables, first transforming the document into the correct structure:

```
.games[].teams[]
  | { tid, ovr, won, lost } + .players[]
  | map(.)
  | @csv
```